# Negative offset in mysql?

Tags: mysql, offset

I want to get the current ID from a table and I used this code which is not working

```
    $query1="SELECT id FROM `login`.`users` LIMIT 2000 OFFSET `id` - 1";
    $result=mysql_query($query1);
```

If the user press the submit button then:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo $row['id'];
    }
```

For example, the current ID = 15, I want to be 14 so I put negative '-' which is not working at all and I can't find a solution for this. Do you  have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see at least 3 problems with your query:

- You have `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`. This is like saying to the database: *"get me 2000 rows from the table, the first 2000, in **whatever order you prefer***." I'm sure you don't want that.
- You can't have variable offset and limit in MySQL. Neither negative. Only hard-coded and positive or zero. (the hard-coded limitation can be bypassed with dynamic SQL but you don't need it here.)
- Even if you could have, and the rows were fetched somehow magically ordered with your wish ordering, `OFFSET 14` might not get you starting from `15`. Surprise, there may be missing `IDs` in the table!

Solution is to use:

```
SELECT id 
FROM login.users 
WHERE id >= 15                 -- the value you want to start from 
ORDER BY id ASC                -- the order
LIMIT 2000                     -- the limit
OFFSET 0 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not reverse the ordering?

```
$query1="SELECT id FROM `login`.`users` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2000, 1";
$result=mysql_query($query1);
```